# What to do if we have to use STRING_SPLIT() and have comma in the data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the parameter @Offer in SSRS which is taking all the data of 'Offer' column which is present in my table(T_OPTYLINE) and now to get only those offers in my report which the user select, I have written the below query in my stored procedure as I am using the stored procedure in my main dataset.

```
select * from T_OPTYLINE where [Offer] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Offer,','))
```

But the issue is in Offer column I have the data like 'Apps integration, development, modernization on prem' and no data comes for this Offer as it has commas present in it.

So how to get the data for the Offers which have commas present in them??

Comment: In this case, you might have to do some processing outside of SQL Server.  There are regex approaches to deal with this; these are basically off limits to SQL Server, which doesn't have any native support for regex.

Comment: Consider just separating with something other than ","?

Comment: Why are you storing it in a comma-separated list in the first place? I assume this is a parameter to a stored procedure or batch, just use a Table-Valued Parameter

Comment: @Charlieface Offer is the parameter present in SSRS. The user will select only the some of the offers from the drop down list and I want only those parameters in my report.
So how will I use the TVP here. Can u pls guide me a bit in that.

Comment: may be replace all commas in that column with a space and then calling the string_split() ?

Comment: Do yo use JOIN to build the parameter string? If you do then use something other than a comma to join the values like the pipe symbol e.g. `=JOIN(Parameters!myParameter.Value , "|")` . You can then use the same in the `string_split` ( `STRING_SPLIT(@Offer,'|')` )

Comment: yaa I am using JOIN and it helped @AlanSchofield. 
Thanks a lot!!!!